# Does guava provide any support for defining ranges of characters?

Tags: java, guava, range

Guava has the ability to define ranges over discrete domains and then create a collection representing those numbers.

Is it possible to create ranges over characters of the modern english latin alphabet?

Maybe [this](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained#Discrete_Domains) suggests that it is not possible, but I don't really understand their definition of a discrete domain:

> A discrete domain always represents the entire set of values of its
>   type; it cannot represent partial domains such as "prime integers",
>   "strings of length 5," or "timestamps at midnight."

Aren't all strings of length 5 a discrete set? Wouldn't a set of all possible latin characters be a definition of a discrete domain?

Comment: `String`s of length 5 don't include the entire set of values of type `String`.

Comment: I think it could be described as a discrete domain though, I guess this is a limitation of their implementation.

Comment: I was confused by this language as well, but I believe the issue is ranges are defined in terms of an ordering.  you can define a Range of strings `["A","C")` such that all strings starting with `A` or `B` of any length are included.  But a range of `strings of length 5 ["A","C")` would include `Apple` and `Brain` but not `Apples` even though lexicographically it's between the two.  It should not be possible to construct a Range `[A,B]` such that `C is not in [A,B]` yet `A <= C <= B`.

Comment: @maaartinus raises a fair point that you *could* create custom class that wraps a string and limits its length to 5 - then you'd have a discrete domain of strings of length 5.  Not a solution I'd really encourage pursuing, but an interesting idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Guava Ranges must be contiguous, you may not be able to use one single Range, but you could certainly create multiple Range objects and combine their set representations to get a collection of the values in the ranges.

```
DiscreteDomain<Character> domain = new DiscreteDomain<Character>(){
  // Implement DiscreteDomain for Character type
};

Range<Character> lower = Ranges.closed('a','z');
Range<Character> upper = Ranges.closed('A','Z');

HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
set.addAll(lower.asSet(domain));
set.addAll(upper.asSet(domain));
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need a `Range` in your code?

Perhaps you can use a `CharMatcher`? It supports only closed ranges, and there is a limited set of operations (and, or, negation), but if this is enough for you, it might be a good alternative.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to create a collection of the values in the range - and this isn't supported with CharMatchers. There are obvious non-guava ways of doing this but I was just wondering if there was a guava specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, everything's possible, it just may not make sense. Even "all strings of length 5" are an interval for an appropriate ordering, however with `Range` supporting `Comparable` but no `Comparator`, you'd need to wrap the string first (which renders the resulting Range quite useless):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static class WrappedString implements Comparable<WrappedString>, Supplier<String> {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        return value;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(WrappedString o) {
        final String s1 = get();
        final String s2 = o.get();
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(s1.length(), s2.length())
            .compare(s1, s2)
            .result();
    }
    @NonNull private final String value;
}

public static Range<WrappedString> rangeOfWrappedStringsOfLength(int length) {
    final char[] a = new char[length];
    final WrappedString lower = new WrappedString(new String(a));
    Arrays.fill(a, Character.MAX_VALUE);
    final WrappedString upper = new WrappedString(new String(a));
    return Ranges.closed(lower, upper);
}
```

A `CharMatcher` is already a predicate and with the "universe" being the set of all characters, it's easy to convert the matcher to a `Set`:

```
private final static ImmutableSet<Character> allChars;
static {
    final ImmutableSet.Builder<Character> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();
    for (int i=Character.MIN_VALUE; i<=Character.MAX_VALUE; ++i) builder.add((char) i);
    allChars = builder.build();
}

public static ImmutableSet<Character> toSet(CharMatcher matcher) {
    return FluentIterable.from(allChars).filter(matcher).toImmutableSet();
}
```

But I doubt it's efficient.

Comment: Why build the ImmutableSet of `allChars` and then filter?  Wouldn't it be simpler to just loop from `MIN_VALUE` to `MAX_VALUE` and add only the chars that pass the filter to the set?

Comment: I think so. I've just implemented my very first idea... and during this I've found out that there's no really simple way for building `allChars`. There'd be a nice way if there was `DiscreteDomains.characters()`. However, this all was just to show that it's possible, and rather than something I'd like to really use.

Comment: Fair enough.  It would be convenient if the Guava devs had implemented a couple more DiscreteDomains, but it wouldn't be too hard to roll your own [DiscreteDomain<Character>](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html) by extending it.

Comment: I [suggested it several months ago](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=860&q=characters&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Package%20Summary), but we didn't have enough use cases to really push on it.  Of course, if a StackOverflow user mentioned their use case on that issue, it might get reconsidered... ::hint hint::